# How can I call a function from itself while avoiding a recursion error in python?

Tags: python, function

I want to run a function with a  while loop in it, and when that while loop breaks I want to execute some code and then run the function again. Currently my code looks like this:

```
def function1():
    while var1 != var2:
        dostuff
    else:
        dootherstuff
        function1() #call the function again
```

While I'm almost certain this is the wrong way to do it, as I get recursion depth exceeded errors every so often, I have no idea how else I would do it. Can someone clear this up please?

Comment: just run your `while <condition>` loop in a `while True` loop ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap it in another loop:

```py
while True:
    while var1 != var2:
        dostuff
    else:
        dootherstuff
```

Python is not designed for deep recursion: use a functional language for that.